# Sending float* from Objective C to C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, unity-game-engine, interopservices

I am making a Unity project and trying to send `float* array` received at `BLE (BlueTooth)` at iPhone to `C# code` at Unity project.

Those function calls initiated from C# to C++ side to receive data by passing array is quite common.
But here, this data transfer is initiated from Objective side to C# when data is received.

I used Plugin to interface to C#.

My `Objective C` side has

`BLEObject.h, BLEObject.m, UnityBridge.h and UnityBridge.mm`.
UnityBridge is C++ code to interface to C#.

UnityBridge.h has

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif 
    void CallMethod(float* array);   

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

UnityBridge.mm has

```
#import "UnityBridge.h"    

void CallMethod(float* objectName)
{
    //some implementation here
}
```

BLEObject.h has

```
+(void) sendMessage:(NSData*)floatArray;
```

BLEObject.m has

```
+(void) sendMessage:(NSData*)floatArray 
{
    //I need to convert here NSData* to float array, how?
    CallMethod(floatArray);
}
```

When I receive data from `BLE, I call [BLEObject sendMessage:floatArray]` at Objective C side.

Then at C# side,

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
    public static extern void CallMethod (float* array);
```

Then I implement CallMethod as

```
public static void CallMethod (float* array){
    //reading array here

}
```

Actually this code doesn't work, but this is the flow I like to implement.
How can I implement that?

Comment: I am implementing the code. Once completed I can discuss in detail. Please don't close for those who are trying to close this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me describe how I implement callback from Objective C to C#.

```
Inside UnityBridge.h and UnityBridge.mm:

typedef void (*UnityCommandCallback) ();

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void ConnectCallback(UnityCommandCallback callbackMethod);    
    void CallMethod();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#import "UnityBridge.h"
//THis is the implementation of methods in the header file
//A static variable to hold our function pointer
static UnityCommandCallback LastCallBack = NULL;
void ConnectCallback(UnityCommandCallback callbackMethod)
{
    LastCallBack = callbackMethod;//a simple assignment using the connect method

}

void CallMethod()
{
    if(LastCallBack != NULL)
        LastCallBack(/*objectName, methodName, parameter*/);
}
```

So this `LastCallBack` memorises the function to call back whenever the event happens at Objective C side.

```
Inside BLEObject.h, BLEObject.m:
```

On top of BLEObject.m, there is a decalaration.

```
extern void CallMethod();
```

So whenever, there is an event, you call this `CallMethod()`.
Since the last call back function is memorised, it will always go back to the same place you want in C#.

Inside C#:
You have this

```
public class BLEBridge : MonoBehaviour {

    public delegate void UnityCallbackDelegate(/*IntPtr objectName, IntPtr methodName, IntPtr parameter*/);
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    public static extern void ConnectCallback(UnityCallbackDelegate callbackMethod);
    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(UnityCallbackDelegate))]
    private static void ManagedTest()
    {
        Debug.Log("IT WORKS!!!!");
    }
}
```

During the initialisation of the C# Object, we call this

```
public static void TestSendMsg()
    {
        ConnectCallback (ManagedTest);
    }
```

So Objective C side knows

```
`ManagedTest()` is the function to call back whenever an event happens at Objective C side.
```

That is how I implement `Callback from Objective C going through C++ interface to C# Unity side`.

Comment: How does this pass the Float array from iOS native to Unity?